# Azure-storage-blob - What is the destination server domain name

Tags: azure, networking, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to whitelist a device that uses python [azure-storage-blob](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/tree/master/azure-storage-blob) package on a firewall. it is directly sending data to the blob storage. 
However I'm not sure which destination FQDN is it using to connect to the blob. If it's getting it from the sas_token, how can I decode it? I see connection attempts, but they are not toward mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net or myaccount.blob.core.windows.net. I can whitelist an IP, but it might be dynamic.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are connecting to an Azure storage account, the default URL for a storage account  is `http://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net` and the default URL for a Blob is `http://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob`. You also can [configure a custom domain for accessing blob data in your Azure storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name).

With a SAS token, you grant clients to access the resources in your storage account. The SAS token is a string you generate on the client side. A SAS token you generate with the storage client library, for example, is not tracked by Azure Storage in any way. Read [how SAS works.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1#how-a-shared-access-signature-works) If you want to whitelist your device to use storage account on a firewall. You can whitelist these [datacenter IP range](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653). If you want to restrict access to your storage account on the Azure side, you can configure [Azure Storage firewalls and virtual networks.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security)

For more references, you can read [Azure Storage security guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-security-guide?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json).

Comment: Thank you for the reply and specifically for the link to the IP range. I had to install tcpdump on the host and look at dns requests to figure out the destination. It was not standard